# How to make div fade in below closest div upon button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, so I have the same button in every div. When it is clicked, I would like Div4 to appear under the div that the user pressed the button in. So, for instance, if user presses Button inside Div2, then Div4 would appear between Div2 and Div3. It would push Div3 down rather than appearing over/hiding Div3.

How can this be achieved, hopefully through jQuery?

Thank you.

```js
$('#Button').click(function() {
  $('#Div4').fadeIn(200);
});
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#Button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: brown;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#Div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
#Div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
#Div3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}
#Div4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div id="Div1">
    Div1
    <div id="Button">Click</div>
  </div>
  <div id="Div2">
    Div2
    <div id="Button">Click</div>
  </div>
  <div id="Div3">
    Div3
    <div id="Button">Click</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There's no `Div4` in your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/2nxd6fon/7/

Instead of same ID for div's (which is not correct approach), use class as shown below,

[As I don't see Div4 in your HTML, I have taken the following approach.]

```
<body>

    <div id="Div1">
        Div1
        <div class="button">Click</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Div2">
        Div2
        <div class="button">Click</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Div3">
        Div3
        <div class="button">Click</div>
    </div>
</body>

var div4Content =  '<div id="Div4">'+
    'Div4'+
    '<div class="button">Click</div>'+
  '</div>';

$('.button').click(function() { 
    $(this).parent().after(div4Content);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, IDs have to be unique, you can't repeat `id="Button"`. You should use a class for that.

You can use `.after()` to move `#Div4` after the current DIV, and then fade it in.

```js
$('.Button').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().after($('#Div4').fadeIn(200));
});
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.Button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: brown;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#Div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
#Div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
#Div3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}
#Div4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div id="Div1">
    Div1
    <div class="Button">Click</div>
  </div>
  <div id="Div2">
    Div2
    <div class="Button">Click</div>
  </div>
  <div id="Div3">
    Div3
    <div class="Button">Click</div>
  </div>
  <div id="Div4">
    Div4
  </div>
</body>
```